# go back from fragment to previous activity onclick back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, onbackpressed

how to go back from fragment to previous activity ?
I can't override this function in the fragment or there is any other way, Need Some Help!

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple activities and you want to go back one activity when you press back button on fragment?

Comment: yes,, i have 3 fragments and I want when i press the back button return me to the activity that had open those fragments

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you likely have a `FragmentTransaction` where you are calling `add()` or `replace()` or `show()` to display the fragment.  In between the display method and `commit()`, if you call `addToBackStack()`, then the operation is added to the back stack, so when you press the back button it reverses your fragment transaction.